# Truncate Notepad-plus-plus search with wildcard

Tags: html, notepad++

I've been unable to explain myself, sorry my failing, so I hope a picture will express what I've failed to explain. Simply, I am trying to remove URL links from a pages of HTML. I don't need to get too fancy, I will deal with the closing tags in a second "search and replace".

So if this works here is a thousand words...[sceen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1lmI.jpg)

Many thanks,
Jeff

Comment: I think you need to edit your question so we can understand what you're asking. Also, some of your code would help explain the problem better

Comment: Have you considered using a HTML parser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somethink like `*?`, a non greedy wildcard:

```
<a .*?</a>
```

Comment: A "non greedy" wild card. Thank you so very much. That is exactly what I needed.